# Is it possible to let my c# wpf program know if the user has a touchscreen or not?

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, touchscreen, login-control

I've got an login application that has a swipe system that people only can use when they have a touchscreen. They can login by swiping their personal pattern swipe code.

Is it possible to check in C# or WPF if the user has a touchscreen? Even when he isn't using touch on it at that time?

Answer (score 21):

Within C# code to find out if a touch screen exists (doesn't check if its a single or multi-touch device though) by the using `System.Windows.Input` namespace in `PresentationCore`.

```
    public bool HasTouchInput()
    {
        foreach (TabletDevice tabletDevice in Tablet.TabletDevices)
        {
            //Only detect if it is a touch Screen not how many touches (i.e. Single touch or Multi-touch)
            if(tabletDevice.Type == TabletDeviceType.Touch)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Why that's not working for me? please look:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923853/why-i-cant-detect-touch-screen

Comment: This worked for me on a Win8 Surface tablet and a Win7 laptop (with touchscreen built in).

Comment: 15 people tested the answer and it works. Why is it not marked as correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything available in managed code but you could use P/Invoke on `Win32_DesktopMonitor`. For more information see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394122%28VS.85%29.aspx).

I found this blog-post that might be of help even though it's on Windows CE: http://blog.nerdbank.net/2006/10/platform-detection-iii-how-to-detect.html

Answer (score 0):

There is [IInkTablet2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) COM interface in Windows XP Tablet PC Edition or managed wrapper [Microsoft.Ink.Tablet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.ink.tablet%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class for non-WPF applications. But it most of touch screen drivers are "mouse" drivers and can't be detected in this way.