# How to detect missing ink-functionality

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-vista

I recently discovered our ink-enabled-application didn't run.
It was a Windows (vista or 7) Netbook.
The inking functionality was ether not installed or missing by design.

So my question is:

**How can I detect** (possible with c#) that **windows is missing the inking functionality** ?

Comment: This question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673556/is-it-possible-to-let-my-c-sharp-wpf-program-know-if-the-user-has-a-touchscreen) suggests that there is a solution to be found using the `Tablet.TabletDevices` property (available in .NET 3.5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two Q. in the [Table PC SDK FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms840459) seem to answer your question though.

Comment: can you or anyone confirm, that System.UI.Input.Inking is missing on some Netbooks ?

Comment: This assembly is on none of my machines. Not surprising considering MS documentation specifies the minimum required client as 'Windows 8 Release Preview' and I only have win7 systems.

Comment: sorry to say, but I was looking for a solution for win7/vista. I have added the according tags

Comment: The solution provided to detect its presence will work on any .Net system. Are you looking at detecting it, or installing it? These are 2 different things.

Comment: Why should I detect this dll as missing if it is ALWAYS missing on vista/win7 ? And I am not able to install it there either...

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what your question is. Is your application based on COM components provided by the [Tablet PC SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms840463.aspx)? Installing said SDK would likely solve your issue.

Comment: @DominiqueJacquel: the question explicitly states Windows 7; your answer is specific to Windows 8 preview.  The question also explicitly asks for how to *detect* the presence of the component, not how to install it.

Comment: unfortunately GetSystemMetrics with SM_TABLETPC does not work. I'll accept your answer though.