# Is there a way to determine if the current screen supports touch?

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, touchscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to let my c# wpf program know if the user has a touchscreen or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673556/is-it-possible-to-let-my-c-sharp-wpf-program-know-if-the-user-has-a-touchscreen)

How can I tell if the device I'm working on has a touch screen?  I'm thinking something like:

```
SystemParameters.IsPenWindows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (TabletDevice tabletDevice in Tablet.TabletDevices)
        {

            if(tabletDevice.Type == TabletDeviceType.Touch)
                return true;
        }
```

you can also refer this one:
[Is it possible to let my c# wpf program know if the user has a touchscreen or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673556/is-it-possible-to-let-my-c-sharp-wpf-program-know-if-the-user-has-a-touchscreen)

Comment: This is a copy-paste of the best voted answer in the duplicate, only with less context and without the comment.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi:  honestly ,i have given reference

Comment: Plagiarizing an answer from a duplicate question is still frowned upon, even if you provide a link (and your link points to the question, not the answer).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: always supporting someone is good thing